# How to replace a substring with a link(http) in swift 3?

Tags: swift, replace, swift3, substring

I have a string and substring(http) and I want to replace that substring but I don't know when that substring will end.  I mean want to check it until one space is not coming and after that I want to replace it.
I am checking that if my string contains http which is also a string then I want to replace it when space will come.

Here below is my example :-

```
let string = "Hello.World everything is good http://www.google.com By the way its good".
```

This is my string It can be dynamic also I mean in this above string http is there, so I want to replace "http://www.google.com" to "website". 
So it would be

```
string = "Hello.World everything is good website By the way its good"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is Regular Expression

The pattern searches for `http://` or `https://` followed one or more non-whitespace characters up to a word boundary.

```
let string = "Hello.World everything is good http://www.google.com By the way its good"
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "https?://\\S+\\b", with: "website", options: .regularExpression)
print(trimmedString)
```

Comment: I was just about to post this but with the regular expression of `"https?://[^ ]*"`. This allows for both http and https.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement. I added the `s?`

Comment: OK Thanks. One more thing is before https I want to add "Website" and I want to keep "http" stuff ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a concrete example of input and output.

Comment: @kishor0011 change `with: "website"` to `with: "website $0"`.

Answer (score 1):

Split each words, replace and join back should solve this.

```
// split into array
let arr = string.components(separatedBy: " ")

// do checking and join
let newStr = arr.map { word in
    return word.hasPrefix("http") ? "website" : word
}.joined(separator: " ")

print(newStr)
```